# Is $\left( \sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|^q \right)^p \leq \left( \sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|^p \right)^q$ correct?

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

Suppose that $p,q \in \mathbb{N},$ $1 \leq p < q \leq \infty.$ 
Denote $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n.$

> Question: For $p\leq q$ and $n \in \mathbb{N},$ is it true that           $$\left(
>  \sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|^q \right)^p \leq \left( \sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|^p
>  \right)^q?$$

My attempt:

We prove the claim by induction on $n.$

When $n=1,$ the claim is trivial.

Suppose that the inequality holds for some $n.$ 
By inductive hypothesis and the fact that $p\leq q,$ we have 
\begin{align*}
\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}|x_k|^q  \right)^p &= \left( \sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|^q + |x_{n+1}|^q \right)^p \\
& \leq \sum_{a=0}^p  \binom{p}{a} \left( \sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|^q \right)^p \left(|x_{n+1}|^q \right)^{p-a} \\
& \leq  \sum_{a=0}^p  \binom{p}{a} \left( \sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|^p \right)^q \left(|x_{n+1}|^p \right)^{q-a} \\
& \leq  \sum_{a=0}^q  \binom{q}{a} \left( \sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|^p \right)^q \left(|x_{n+1}|^p \right)^{q-a} \\
& = \left( \sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|^p + |x_{n+1}|^p \right)^q \\
& = \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}|x_k|^p \right)^q.
\end{align*}

Is my proof correct?

Comment: This approach uses crucially the assumption that $$\left(|x_{n+1}|^q \right)^{p-a} \leqslant \left(|x_{n+1}|^p \right)^{q-a}$$ Why would this be so?

Comment: @Did: I just realize that the inequality holds for $x_{n+1} \geq 1$ only.

Comment: Re the question in the title, indeed the inequality holds, since it is equivalent to the comparison between $\ell^p$ and $\ell^q$ norms $$\left( \sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|^q \right)^{1/q} \leq \left( \sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|^p \right)^{1/p}$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm rewritting in more detail the 1st inequality :
$$
\left(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^q + |x_{n+1}|^p \right)^p = \sum_{a=0}^p \binom{p}{a} \underbrace{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^q\right)^a}_{A} \underbrace{|x_{n+1}^p|^{p-a}}_{B}
$$
Then you claim that $B \leq |x_{n+1}^q|^{p-a}$ which is not true if $|x_{n+1}| \leq 1$.

Also $A$ may not be $\leq \left(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^q\right)^p$ if the sum is $\leq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $|x_k|^p=a_k$ and $\frac{q}{p}=r$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^r\geq a_1^r+a_2^r+...+a_n^r.$$
Now, let $f(x)=x^r$ and $a_1\geq a_2\geq...\geq a_n$.

Hence, $f$ is a convex function and $(a_1+a_2+...+a_n,0,...,0)\succ(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$.

Id est, by Karamata
$$f(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)+f(0)+...+f(0)\geq f(a_1)+f(a_2)+...+f(a_n),$$ which is
$$(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^r\geq a_1^r+a_2^r+...+a_n^r$$ and we are done!